# WCF, SignalR or websockets for webchat

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, websocket, signalr

I am trying to develop web chat integrated to site on ASP.NET. What technology for messaging is better to use for it? Please tell about benefits or disadvantages of each other.
I will be very glad to each answer. I incline to using SignalR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't include WCF just for the fact that it is more of a technology for building services that serve the data you want.

So it really boils down to websockets and SignalR.

websockets are a techonolgy to allow bi-directional communication in a web environment.  Of course it isn't supported by all browsers.

SignalR is a library the rolls multiple communication technologies together.  EG: websockets & long-polling.  It is the better choice for your question as it will automatically take care of the technology that can be used to accomplish the bi-directional communication you seek.

Comment: Please explain why You don't include WCF. As I know WCF use for developing of charts is very common practise.

Comment: I did.  WCF is more for building services and serving data.  It isn't like websockets and SinglR where they solely are used to create a bi-directional link to a server and pushing it down.  WCF can't be used natively in a browser like that.  You CAN make a WCF service and use AJAX to call it though.

Comment: Thanks. May be you know some facts about productivity of these technologies?

Answer (score 1):

- WCF is for tick-client apps; it is not designed to be consumed from a browser.
- Signalr is a wrapper around web sockets (with fallbacks) and is what you want to use
- WebSockets is a protocol with various implementations in different languages.

For non-real-time scenarios, you would want ASP.Net Web API.

Comment: It should work for real time scenarios.